# MediaRouteController Dialog Crash Issue

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast, android-api-levels

I am getting these error logs when I tap on **MediaRouteButton** after my Android App is connected to ChromeCast device. App was working fine when I was using Google Play Services Api 6.5 and this happened when I switched to target my App for Android Api 22 and Play Services Api to 7.5+.

Working fine with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:6.5.87'
```

App crash with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.5.0'
```

Error Logs:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
            at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:480)
            at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteControllerDialog.onCreate(MediaRouteControllerDialog.java:211)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:364)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
            at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:399)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1813)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:989)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
            at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:480)
            at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteControllerDialog.onCreate(MediaRouteControllerDialog.java:211)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:364)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
            at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:399)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1813)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:989)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010090 a=-1}
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3415)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
            at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:88)
            at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
            at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:480)
            at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteControllerDialog.onCreate(MediaRouteControllerDialog.java:211)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:364)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
            at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:399)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1813)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:989)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Something is happening with your MediaRouteControllerDialog. There isn't enough info here to make any useful suggestion so it would be good if you can create a small minimal project that exhibits this issue and share the project so we can take a look. Also please move to the latest versions of the play services and support libraries.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How can I share project with you ?

Comment: Here is link for Sample test project with issue       [link](https://clientteam.s3.amazonaws.com/PlaystoreApp/Archive.zip)

Comment: That is a full project with too many classes and fragments and other stuff in it; it crashes as soon as I run it, so please create a minimal test project that exhibits that issue with no additional/extra stuff, not your full application. Also, in general, when you set your compileSdkVersion to, say, 23, then you need to use support libraries v23.*; those two should match.

Comment: Solved the issue it was App theme which was causing crash. I set it to 'Theme.AppCompat'  and crash is fixed. Thank you very much for replying and sparing your precious time.